# Gremlin > recursively find nodes connected by an edge type

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-blueprint

Just working with the [TinkerGraph](https://github.com/tinkerpop/blueprints/wiki/Property-Graph-Model), and attempting to recursively find nodes connected by a specific edge label (in this case `created`).

1. Is there a way I can recursively(/loop) traverse nodes? In the example below, I want to loop until there are no more matching edges (instead of the hardcoded `3` value).
2. Is there anyway to find and group connected Vertices, given a graph?

Extra kudos for deduplicating nodes, and handling node loops.

#### Dependencies

```groovy
compile("com.thinkaurelius.titan:titan-berkeleyje:0.5.4")
compile('com.tinkerpop:gremlin-groovy:2.6.0')
```

#### Code (manually recurse 3 times :( )

```groovy
Gremlin.load()
def g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
println g.v(5).as('x')
    .both('created')
    .dedup
    .loop(2){it.loops <= 3}
    .path
    .toList().flatten() as Set // groovy code to flatten & dedup
```

#### Gives me: (correct)

```groovy
[v[5], v[4], v[3], v[1], v[6]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this mean you don't want to walk over a vertex you've already visted in the traversal?

Comment: @D.Mill , I don't mind which method is used to get a group of connected nodes. It sounds logical though (depending on your approach) that you wouldn't want to traverse the same vertex twice (to avoid infinite loops), right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need any Groovy code, it can be done by only using Gremlin:

```
gremlin> g.v(5).as('x').both('created').dedup()
gremlin>     .loop('x') {true} {true}.dedup()
==>v[4]
==>v[3]
==>v[5]
==>v[6]
==>v[1]
```

Comment: Brilliant, just what I was looking for! Can you explain why the `loop('x') {true} {true}` doesn't just loop indefinitely? I've read the docs, but don't understand how your loop works... http://gremlindocs.com/#branch/loop

Comment: It can't loop without if there's no path left (under the hood a FastNoSuchElementException is thrown). The `.dedup()` in `.both('created').dedup()` ensures the no path is traversed twice.

Comment: That's really cool. I threw in a loop back `g.v(6).addEdge('created', g.v(4))`, and it didn't even blink. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my current solution. It's a work in progress, so I'm more than happy for improvements and suggestions. (Surely it could be optimised using Gremlin syntax?)

**Assumptions:** we're given a start node

```groovy
Gremlin.load()
def g = TinkerGraphFactory.createTinkerGraph()
def startV = g.v(5)
def seen = [startV] // a list of 'seen' vertices
startV.as('x')
    .both('created')
    .filter { // only traverse 'unseen' vertices
        def unseen = !seen.contains(it)
        if (unseen){
            seen << it
        }
        unseen
    }
    .loop('x'){
        // continue looping while there are still more 'created' edges...
        it.object.both('created').hasNext() // ##
    }
    .toList() // otherwise won't process above pipeline
println seen
```

**##** I'm not sure why this condition works/doesn't find previously traversed edges. Can anyone explain?

Gives me:

```groovy
[v[4], v[5], v[3], v[1], v[6]]
```